# Button doesn't call the function for the first click

Tags: vue.js

I have a checkbox and a button that when it's checked, then, the button suppose to submit, but when it's unchecked, the button is disable.

However, my button keep disabling and I can't submit, the reason because I add: v-on:click.prevent="checkboxJsInput"

The reason I use "prevent" is because I have disable and enable button, and "prevent" is to disable the button from submit when it's disable.

If I don't use "prevent", the button would submit even it's disable and the strange thing it's enable for the first time, but after you "check" for the second and so on, it's working.

My question, how to make the button works?
so when the button is grey, it's supposed to disable, when it's blue, it's supposed to enable to submit.
Is there a way to do this in vue way rather than using native javascript in vue?

```js
checkboxJsInput: function() {
      const checkBox = document.querySelector(".guestlistCheckboxJs");
      const buttonFormJs = document.querySelector(".buttonCheckboxJs");

      if (checkBox != null) {
        checkBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
          if (this.checked) {
            buttonFormJs.disabled = false;
            buttonFormJs.classList.remove("disabled");
          } else {
            buttonFormJs.disabled = true;
            buttonFormJs.classList.add("disabled");
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.buttonCheckboxJs.disabled {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-checkbox {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
}

.guestlist-text-checkbox {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}

.guestlist-input-checkbox[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #d6d6d6;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
    inset 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.guestlist-span-checkbox {
  visibility: visible;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4990e2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.guestlist-input-checkbox[type="checkbox"]:checked
  + label
  .guestlist-span-checkbox::before {
  content: "✔";
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-textarea {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.guestlist-textarea {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-indent: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ffffff;
}


.button-style {
  background-color: #4990e2;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-checkbox">
            <input
              class="guestlist-input-checkbox guestlistCheckboxJs"
              v-on:click="checkboxJsInput"
              type="checkbox"
              value="1"
              name="OptIn"
              id="OptIn"
            >

            <label class="guestlist-label-checkbox" for="OptIn">
              <span class="guestlist-span-checkbox"></span>
            </label>

          </div>

          <button
            v-on:click.prevent="checkboxJsInput"
            class="button-style buttonCheckboxJs disabled"
          >Check Availability</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using v-model for this.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components

Your checkbox can have its v-model bound to a data property, and the disabled property on the button can be bound to the same. It'd look like this:

```
<template>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="enableSubmit" />
  <button @click="mySubmitFunction()" :disabled="!enableSubmit">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        enableSubmit: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      mySubmitFunction() {
        //...
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, didn't know we can use vue way with v-model, I thought I need to use vanilla

Answer (score 3):

First of all I don't understand why you are using an event listner inside an event listner for that checkbox click.
Secondly, you can use `v-model`.
In your data, add property `check` like this:

```
data() {
   return {
     check: false
   }
}
```

Then in your html use like this:

```
<div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-checkbox">
            <input
              class="guestlist-input-checkbox guestlistCheckboxJs"
              v-model="check"
              type="checkbox"
              value="1"
              name="OptIn"
              id="OptIn"
            >

            <label class="guestlist-label-checkbox" for="OptIn">
              <span class="guestlist-span-checkbox"></span>
            </label>

          </div>

          <button
            :disabled="check"
            class="button-style buttonCheckboxJs disabled"
          >Check Availability</button>
```

I just use a check property which is a boolean. Then you can run your function on click of that button.

Comment: Thanks, it's working, didn't know we can use vue way with v-model, I thought I need to use vanilla